# how can I call two functions: Java and Javascript with one KeyUp event on InputText

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

how can I call two functions: Java and Javascript with one KeyUp event on InputText , i'm using Primefaces component.
something like this :

```
<p:inputText id="aa"
    value="#{bonBonneManagedBean.sel}">
    <p:ajax event="keyup" Onstart="fnc(this)"
    listener="#{bonBonneManagedBean.ajouterSelected(bonBonneManagedBean.sel)}" />
</p:inputText>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close. You've only a typo in the `onstart` attribute. It should be written in all lowercase.

```
<p:ajax event="keyup" onstart="fnc(this)"
    listener="#{bonBonneManagedBean.ajouterSelected(bonBonneManagedBean.sel)}" />
```

Refer the [VDL documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/) for right attribute names.

Comment: Please elaborate "not working" in developer's perspective instead of in enduser's perspective.

Comment: function works fine when I use : <p:inputText id="aa" onkeyup="fnc(this)" value="#{bonBonneManagedBean.sel}"/> but with ajax event gives error

Comment: That's a different problem. You've just a JS logic error inside `fnc()` function. As the message says, the object behind the `inputComponent` variable doesn't have a `value` property. Your concrete question is answered: the onstart function is invoked and the listener method is invoked (once you fix that logic error in JS function).